# How can i identiy fast indirect relations in a dependency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dependencies

```
 |A  |B  |C  |
A|Nan|x  |x  |
B|x  |Nan|Nan|
C|x  |Nan|Nan|
```

I have this example from a csv file and with Pandas i managed to remove X and Nan values and replace them with 0/1

```
 |A|B|C|
A|0|1|1|
B|1|0|0|
C|1|0|0|
```

My aim is to find and add the indirect relations. For example if A has a depedency to B and C, then add the value 1 to B and C elements. My table is more than 400 elements, so i can choose every element by column name, therefor i will use for loops to map the coordinates of the values 1 and then find the indirect relation. For example: 1,2 and 1,3 have a Value of 1, then 2,3 and 3,2 will have also the value 1. My result should be like this table:

```
 |A|B|C|
A|0|1|1|
B|1|0|1|
C|1|1|0|
```

Does anyone have another idea for an easier way or has seen something similar. The difficult part for me is the creation of the 1 values in the table, where i am not sure how it can be done.

Comment: can you provide a slightly more complex example with variables without dependency? Also please don't use `|` for table formatting (or better provide a DataFrame constructor)

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a graph problem.

Starting from this input (I added 2 more nodes D/E):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0]],
                  columns=list('ABCDE'), index=list('ABCDE'))

   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  1  1  0  0
B  1  0  0  0  0
C  1  0  0  0  0
D  0  0  0  0  1
E  0  0  0  1  0
```

You have the following graph:

[image: graph]

and want to find all edges:

[image: graph2]

For this you can start by constructing a list of edges:

```
df2 = df.where(df.eq(1)).stack().rename_axis(['source', 'target']).reset_index()

  source target    0
0      A      B  1.0
1      A      C  1.0
2      B      A  1.0
3      C      A  1.0
4      D      E  1.0
5      E      D  1.0
```

Then compute a graph with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/) and get the connected components (i.e. the disconnected subgroups):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2)

groups = nx.connected_components(G)

# NB. the above is a generator which gives
# [{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E'}]
```

Finally, generate the list all edges pairs with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and create the desired output:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(chain.from_iterable(permutations(l, 2)
                                for l in nx.connected_components(G)))

out = pd.Series(index=idx).fillna(1, downcast='infer').unstack(fill_value=0)

   A  B  C  D  E
A  0  1  1  0  0
B  1  0  1  0  0
C  1  1  0  0  0
D  0  0  0  0  1
E  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to test this approach?

Comment: Yeap, i can say it was usefull, but i still get some error generating the table with the last code lines and now i try to resolve it!
"FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  out = pd.Series(index=idx).fillna(1, downcast='infer').unstack(fill_value=0)"
My example is a table 421x421

I get this warning and in the table instead of A,B,C,D,E i get a table of 820x820, with some rows and columns full with numbers, so i have to research the code to understand, why is that.

Comment: If you have anaother idea then i am open for suggestions. But i find your approache very good! Also i exported the result table in excel and it was corrupted, so i have to try to identify the reason for that. But thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I found my error. My index was listed as numbers and i column 1 was the index i wanted. Do you have any idea how can i add the new relationships with another color. For your example B and C, so someone can identify which relationship is direct and indirect?

Comment: You can compare the original and new dataframes. The 1s common to both and the new 1s can have a different color

Comment: Okay i will try to compare them. Still i am trying to set the index and columns names correct, because in the initial table i have 421 x 421 and the new generated code has 410x410 elements (but in Pycharm terminal i have a matrix 420x420, that is extremely weird) and i am not sure why.  I will try to generate your code for  a table with numeric index and columns and then replace them with there real index and columns